# How to correctly wire two lamps to 2 way switch

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light, multiway-switch

I messed up! I was replacing two light fittings that are both controlled from 2  two way switches.

I did not make a note of the existing connections before I removed the old fittings (noob mistake I know).

Anyway I connected the 2 browns(live) together and the two blues(neutral) together and the 2 yellows(earth) together. When I switched back on the lights worked but now are linked to another light. (Switching that light on switches these two on and switching these two on switches the other light on)

I realise I need a "loop" for the switch - but not sure what needs to go to the fixture and what needs to be joined together.
B
[image: picture at light fitting]

There are two 3 core cables going to each fitting.  Here is a picture of what I currently have for both fittings - can anyone tell me what what I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out - One of the browns was just a "live feed" - so I could isolate the other brown coming into that fitting.
This probably doesn't make any sense - but I was able to figure out which one I could isolate by trial and error.